# Caching tables not clearing out

Tags: database, cache

We are running Craft on a site that gets a decent level of traffic, thousands of hits per day. We are running craft caching to try and keep things quick. The caching tables have been growing significantly over the past few days and don't appear to be clearing out. These are the three tables and the row counts. 1+ million rows in two of them.

| craft_templatecaches                |      34685 |
| craft_templatecachecriteria         |    1197874 |
| craft_templatecacheelements         |    1364424 |

Any ideas on why these tables would be growing so large and why they don't appear to be removing any old rows?

Comment: Could you be using the cache tag without the `globally` parameter so you get one set of cached content per URL?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you probably have a stuck or error'd "Delete Stale Template Cache" task.

You can tell if a task is stuck because there will be a circular progress bar in the upper-right hand corner of the CP that isn't progressing.

If it error'd, it will be red and you'll have the option to re-try it.

Regardless, here's the general troubleshooting steps necessary for both cases: http://buildwithcraft.com/help/stuck-tasks